# How to cancel the commit while the Source Control VSCode is waiting for the commit message?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm testing the VSCode's Source Control, and I recklessly hit the `commit` button; now it's waiting for me to enter the commit message:
[image]

Is there a way to cancel and terminate the whole commit process in this situation?

Comment: and if that didn't work and the commit was done, you can hit the 3 dots, near the refresh, you will find a section called commit -> undo last commit, if you don't make a push nothing will happen

Comment: @haruk1515 depends if you have staged partial content of some files (changes in workfile and index), I don't know what VSC does if you undo a commit, a hard reset or a soft reset

Comment: @rioV8 I had used several times the "undo last commit", is a soft reset, and you don't lose any unstaged changes, so in my experience I guess it's safe way

Comment: I was amending all my changes instead of staged, and closing the tab did not stop it :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just close the COMMIT_EDITMSG tab, should cancel the commit ;)

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out that the message itself (the one in the editor, and which is shown in your screenshot) is pretty instructive:

> an empty message aborts the commit.

Close the editor with an empty message (no need to touch the commented lines). The same goes for any other commit message editor program other than VS Code. Ex. vim.